# How do I get a File handle for a jar:file?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm including file resources (via `src/main/resources`) in a Gradle plugin that is published as a JAR.

In the clients that use the library, how do I access these files? The `file` method does not seem to support the `jar:file` scheme:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'sc.snd.gradle.library.codequality.CodeQualityPlugin']
> Cannot convert URL 'jar:file:/Users/matthiaskappler/.m2/repository/sc/snd/gradle/library-plugin/0.1/library-plugin-0.1.jar!/rules/checkstyle/modules.xml' to a file.
```

In the docs for `file` it indeed says it can only handle ordinary `file://` URLs.

Is there any way to access these files without having to explode the JAR into the client first? That seems messy.

Comment: Not sure if this is any use? http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/referencing-a-resource-in-gradle-td4359379.html

Comment: @Matthias, it seems that you should read this file via `classLoader`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for getting back! The problem isn't with loading the resource itself though, that works fine. However, `getResource` returns a file URL with scheme `jar:file://` which Gradle's `Project#file` doesn't accept. What I do now is I use `getResourceAsStream#getText` to dump the file contents into the project folder. That works but wasn't my preferred solution really.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but it is still open. Maybe this helps anyone.

The ZipTree functionality should help ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:archive_contents)). It lets you access an archive file like a directory structure.